# Asp:fileupload using without fullpostback

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, file-upload, webforms

I'm currently employed in web application development, specifically working with the ASP.NET Web Forms framework (not MVC), and I primarily use JavaScript and C# in my tech stack. My knowledge in web app development is relatively new.

Within my current project, I've implemented a modal popup that contains an ASP file upload control and an upload button. To ensure a smooth user experience without a full page refresh, both the file upload control and the upload button are enclosed within an update panel. However, I encountered a challenge when trying to validate the FileUpload.HasFile property without initiating a full postback.

To address this issue, I've used triggers within the update panel. My objective is to maintain a seamless user experience, but there's a problem: when a full postback occurs, the page refreshes, and the popup closes abruptly. This disrupts the workflow and creates multiple obstacles. I'm seeking advice or ideas on how to achieve seamless file upload validation within the popup modal without it closing when a full postback occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The standard HTML file upload control (or the asp.net one, which is the same control) requires post-back to work correctly. Not only does the file upload control require a full-page post back, but using an update panel job is to prevent and NOT have a page post back in the first place.

What this means is that you CAN NOT use the standard file upload control inside of an update panel. In fact, you can't use the file upload control if your goal is to NOT have a page post-back.

So, since an update panel does not post back the whole web page, then you can't use a file upload control inside of an update panel.

However, in this day and age, there are MANY great examples of a file up-loader utility and controls available (many for free). And in most cases, such controls can be used inside of an update panel (they don't require a post-back to upload files).

In fact, since many of these ajax async uploader controls don't need nor trigger a post back?

Then in most cases you don't need nor want an update panel anyway, right?

The other advantages are many, such as most of these controls show an uploading progress bar (from a UI and usability point of view, the built-in file upload control is nothing short of abuse of humans).

In most cases these ajax uploader libraries work inside of a say a jQuery.UI dialog popup form. And, once again, since these controls don't post-back, nor require a page post-back, then the control not only works inside of an update panel (which you probably don't need anymore!!!), but such controls EVEN work inside of a jQuery.UI popup dialog.

So, say like this:

[image]

Note in above, we have a select button (to select one, or many files), or you can use drag and drop hot spot as I did above (again, those drag + drop hotspot is a feature of most of these uploader controls).

Despite the above uploader being inside of a popup dialog, no post-backs occur, and thus the pop dialog (a jquery.UI dialog) is able to remain open during selecting of files, and uploading of files.

The upload control used in above is the free open source one from the AjaxTookit. That toolkit is now maintained by the great folks at DevExpress.

And there are many other choices for up-loader controls, just google for some additional examples.

I thus suggest you adopt a nice well written uploader control, and one that does not require a post-back. As above shows, you in many cases will then eliminate the need for an update panel.

The other advantages of using a ajax up-loader is they up-load files in small chunks and that means no limit on file size. And as above shows, since the file is being up-loaded in chunks, then the user has a nice progress bar as opposed to some page that seems to freeze up when using a standard file upload control.

You can find the free open source AjaxTookkit by using NuGet, or you can grab a copy from DevExpress here:

https://www.devexpress.com/Products/AJAX-Control-Toolkit/

As noted, the above AjaxFileUploader is one of many free examples.

The simple point I make here is that with so many great example file upload controls to be had for free, then it makes little sense to use the HTML file upload control. As above shows, such controls result in a far better user experience and a more up to date uploading experience that users have come to expect when using the internet.

So, the markup I used for the above uploader looks like this:

```
    <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" 
                                AllowedFileTypes="pdf,zip" 
        ChunkSize="8192" 
        ClientIDMode="Static"
        ViewStateMode="Enabled" 
        title="test" MaximumNumberOfFiles="40"
        OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete"
        OnClientUploadCompleteAll="myalldone"
        OnClientUploadStart="myuploadstart"
        OnClientUploadComplete="onefiledone"
            />
```

So, in the above example, the AjaxFileUpload is a custom control from the AjaxToolkit. I thus was able to simple drag and drop the above control from the tool box into the web form. The above resulting markup creates a nice file uploader control on the given form.

As above shows, there is a set of server side events that run (without a postback), and also a set of client side (JavaScript) events that also run. So choice of code at start of uploading, when one file is completed uploading, and at end of uploading all files are options you have with above control.

Comment: [HttpException (0x80004005): The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).] this error occur

Comment: Start a new question and provide the markup and code as an reproducible error